# How to add route map along with traffic layers

Tags: google-maps

I am doing a road traffic analysis and  prediction a project.
In this i am using maps of locations using lat,long .
i want the traffic layers between source a and source b . 
for example consider pes university as source A , ISRO layout as source B,
I want the traffic layer between source and destination. How can i get that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Google Maps API doesn't expose traffic data between two points.

Note that there was a feature request for traffic data in Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112008136

Unfortunately, Google rejected this feature request with the following answer

> Thanks for your post.
>
> However, this request does not fit in any of the Maps APIs scope / offering.
>
> The Maps JavaScript API does offer a Traffic Layer for visualizing traffic on a map:
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-traffic
>
> The Directions API offers duration_in_traffic for each route.
>
> Exposing traffic data in other forms is not in the scope of the Maps APIs.